# Why does Frank's car not have a license plate at the front?

Tags: plot-explanation, transporter-2

In Transporter 2, Frank's car has a license plate at the back:

[image: back view]

but not the front:

[image]

[images from here](http://www.imcdb.org/movie_388482-Transporter-2.html)

I noticed this, because if I remember correctly, in the first movie in the series, the license plate could be changed with the push of a button.

Why is this? Don't you need a licence plate at both ends?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.  Florida does not require a license plate at both ends.**

Transporter 2 is set in Miami, Florida, U.S.A.  Florida is one of the U.S. states which do not require a license plate at both ends.

There's a handy map here: [Which States Don't Require A Front License Plate](https://www.cars.com/articles/2013/10/which-states-dont-require-a-front-license-plate/)

A copy of the map:

[image]

Comment: The answer is right, but is that map accurate? I live in Texas and see many cars with no front license plate (although the back seems to be a special one for dealers/manufacturers)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - no idea.  I don't live in the U.S.  The article where I found the map is from 2013, so things might have changed.  Laws could be different for dealer plates, which usually require only the rear plate to be displayed.

Comment: I live in a state that requires front LP but also see many cars that don't have one. Its important to understand that people don't always comply with the law.

Comment: @sanpaco or maybe they are from states that don't need one at the front and they are allowed to drive through your state without installing one.